# Setting a dynamic default value for a field in Keystone (for a url slug)

Tags: typescript, graphql, keystonejs

Im totally new to both GraphQL and the concept of headless CMS having only ever built my own REST API's from scratch.

I've built out a basic API using Keystone v6 and lets say I have a Schema for products something like:

```
export const Item = list({
  fields: {
    name: text({ validation: { isRequired: true } }),
    description: text(),
    photos: relationship({
      ref: 'ProductImage.listing',
      many: true,
    }),
    category: relationship({
      ref: 'Category.listings',
      many: false,
    }),
    dateCreated: timestamp({
      defaultValue: { kind: 'now' },
    }),
    brand: text(),
    model: text(),
    size: text(),
    slug: text(),
  },
});
```

Cool, works.... Now say I want slug to be auto populated when a product is created with the something like ' "this-item-name" + "-" + "id" ' I cant figure out a/ how to do this or b/ even from a convention standpoint where to.

My assumption would be that i would use the `defaultValue` attribute of the text field? or would this be something to do with a mutation (a concept i'm not wrapping my head around very well yet)... and if so I cant figure out where in a boilerplate Keystone app I would even write a mutation.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `defaultValue` option won't help you as Keystone 6 only supports static defaults and here we want to default a value dynamically.

@Daniel's suggestion of a virtual field *half works* – it's a good way to derive one value from another – but virtual fields run when when the value is *read* from the DB.
As such, you can't filter by a virtual field so, if you used one here, you'd never be able to find an item based on it's slug (which is one of the main things you're going to want to do).

**What you need here is a [hook](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/hooks).**

Hooks are a Keystone feature that give you a way to run code before and after operations are performed on the GraphQL API. They let you attach functions at different points in the mutation lifecycle (eg, `beforeOperation`, `afterOperation`, etc.), causing them to run at different times.

When invoked, the hook function is passed information about where and why it's being run (such the `listKey` or `fieldKey` and the `operation` being performed), along with the incoming data, existing data and [Keystone `context` object](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/context), allowing you to query the API within a hook.

You can also attach hooks at two different levels: the list level, where they'll have access to an entire operation, or the field level, where they can only effect the behaviour of a single field.

It sounds a little complicated but the
[Hooks Guide](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/hooks) and the [Hooks API](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/hooks)
pages on the Keystone docs site should have you covered.

In concrete terms, you probably want something like this:

```js
// A simple function to derive a url-safe value from a string input
// We'll use this from within out hook
function buildSlug(input) {
  return input
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[^\w ]+/g, '')
    .replace(/ +/g, '-');
}

// Define the list schema
export const Item = list({
  fields: {
    name: text({ validation: { isRequired: true } }),
    // ... all the other fields

    // Declare the `slug` as a normal text field
    slug: text({

      // Being a slug, it should be indexed for lookups and unique
      isIndexed: 'unique',

      // Define the hook function itself and attach it to the resolveInput
      // step of the mutation lifecycle
      hooks: {
        resolveInput: ({ operation, resolvedData, inputData }) => {

          // Lets only default the slug value on create and only if 
          // it isn't supplied by the caller.
          // We probably don't want slugs to change automatically if an 
          // item is renamed.
          if (operation === 'create' && !inputData.slug) {
            return buildSlug(inputData.name);
          }

          // Since this hook is a the field level we only return the 
          // value for this field, not the whole item
          return resolvedData.slug;
        },
      },
    }),
  },
});
```

You can see we've attached our hook at the `resolveInput` step of the mutation lifecycle.
This is a good place to modify incoming values before they're saved:

> The `resolveInput` function is used to modify or augment the data values passed in to a create or update operation.
> — [Hooks API docs](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/hooks#resolve-input)

Note we've used `isIndexed: 'unique'` to enforce uniqueness at the database level.
As written, this will cause create operations to error if they would otherwise result in duplicate values.
All hooks are passed the [Keystone `context` object](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/context) and can be async so you could, if you wanted, ensure the generated value was unique by checking the database before returning.

Here, We've put our hook at the field level.
We could also have written it at the list level but we're only modifying a single value so this is a little clearer to read.

Comment: Ah, having re-read the question, I see that @Daniel suggestion of a virtual field actually _would_ work as you're planning to put both the "slug" and the item id in the actual URL. Ie. the "slug" part is for appearance only and not used for lookups – you can just extract the ID from the URL and lookup the item with it. If that's your use case, a virtual field would work pretty well.

Comment: I've marked both answers correct as, as you said, in different use cases which hadn't been specified in my question both could useful... as it happens, I have ended up with a variation of yours as you were correct in that being able to lookup by slug was better for me ;) Thanks very much for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is called `virtual field`
with the `resolver` function, you can get all of the item fields and use a string template to construct whatever you need, just put this code as another field of type virtual

```
virtualName: {
      type: Virtual,
      resolver: item => `${item.name}-${item.id}`
      };
    },
```

I think my syntax is for keystone 5 but it should be similar to what you need, Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Whilst not the route I took for this particular problem, learning about virtual fields was incredibly useful and I have put it to use elsewhere.  thanks.

Comment: Though conceptually they're the same, the syntax for virtual fields in Keystone v6 has changed from v5. See the [Virtual Fields guide](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/virtual-fields) for current usage.